# Ionic 3 Google Maps issue after upgrade to WKWebview

Tags: google-maps, ionic-framework, wkwebview

I'm working on Ionic 3, testing with iPhone 7 plus and iOS 11, and I've just updated to WKWebview, and now I'm having issues with my Google Maps ionic native plugin. This is the error I'm getting when testing on my device:

> ClientParametersRequest failed, 7 attempts remaining (0 vs 10). Error Domain=com.google.HTTPStatus Code=400 "(null)" UserInfo={data=<3c44d ...........>}`

I'm not 100% sure, but I think it's some issue with CORS, which is now required with WKWebview.

I've read in a few places that you can bypass it via a Proxy, by adding the following in your `ionic.config.json` files:

````
```
  "proxies": [
    {
      "path": "http://localhost:8080",
      "proxyUrl": "https://maps.googleapis.com"
    }
  ],
```
````

But it's not working, and I'm not sure if I got the path and proxyURL correct.

UPDATE:

So, now we know it's not about CORS, as it's a BAD REQUEST 400, so the data I'm sending is bad, as CORRECTLY NOTED BELOW IN THE COMMENTS BY sideshowbarker. I've tested the code and it fails on line 2 this JS code, where I try to subscribe to the event.

```
 mapMoveSubscribe() {
    this.map.addEventListener(GoogleMapsEvent.CAMERA_IDLE).subscribe(() => {   
      this.map.getCameraPosition().then((cameraPosition) => {
        this.temp = JSON.stringify(cameraPosition.target);
        this.temp2 = JSON.parse(this.temp);
        this.currentLatitude = this.temp2.lat;
        this.currentLongitude = this.temp2.lng;
        this.nativeGeocoder.reverseGeocode(this.currentLatitude ? this.currentLatitude : 0, this.currentLongitude ? this.currentLongitude : 0).then((result: NativeGeocoderReverseResult) => {
          this.locationObject = (result.thoroughfare ? result.thoroughfare + ' ' : '') + (result.subThoroughfare ? result.subThoroughfare + ', ' : '') + (result.locality == result.administrativeArea ? '' : result.locality + ', ') + (result.administrativeArea ? result.administrativeArea + ' ' : '') + (result.postalCode ? result.postalCode + ', ' : '') + (result.countryName ? result.countryName : '');

          this.geoObject = result;
        }).catch((error: any) => console.log(error));
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: *HTTPStatus Code=400* indicates it's not a CORS issue but instead some problem with the data you're POSTing. The 400 means "bad request", indicating that there's something about the request which is not what the receiving server expected. For example, if your request is a POST, the problem could be that the data you're POSTing is not in the format the receiving server expects.

Comment: @sideshowbarker that's strange, as I haven't changed the code at all after upgrading to WKWebview. Any idea what it could be?

Comment: Dunno but one thing you might want to consider doing: Update the question to paste in the snippet of your JavaScript code that shows how the request is being made. Also, using whatever equivalent of the Network pane in browser devtools you have available, examine the requests the browser engine is making — including the request headers and HTTP method — and the responses it’s getting back, and then also paste those details into the question

Comment: @sideshowbarker Thanks! I've update the question. I'm testing native plugins, so can do this only on devices, so browser tools are out. I've managed to track the line where execution of the code stops and I get this ERROR.